# How to check if an element from a list exists in mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

I have this list:

```
myList = [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)]
```

and this query:

```
query = "SELECT date_ FROM set_payment7777"
mycursor.execute(query)
for row in mycursor:
    if date_ in myList:
        print("done")
```

but it doesn't really work. Any solutions?

Notice: date_ in the table is a datetime.date object

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    cur.execute("SELECT date_ FROM set_payment777")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    date_ = datetime.date(2021,1,3)
    for r in rows:
       if date_ == r[0]:
          print("done")
```